# Image Picker Cordova plugin does not return file uri's

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using **imagepicker** plugin to select multiple images at a time within my ionic 2 app. It shows all images, we can set a maximum number of select images too , but it does not return a proper path. It shows some cache path , such as 
`file:///data/data/io.cordova.myapp72eec3/cache/tmp_DSC_000899887878782.jpg`.
I didn't create the folder named `io.cordova.myapp72eec3`, it gets automatically created and it does not physically have even a single image in its cache sub-folder. Please help me to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

That is normal, as far as I know you can do whatever you like using that path on IOS, but thats not the case in Android you need to copy the file to another folder and then access it through the new url. Below is a sample code:

```
function makeid() {
var text = '';
var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
return text;
};

function saveMedia(type) {
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
  var options = optionsForType(type);

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {
    var name = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var namePath = imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var newName = makeid() + name;
    $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newName)
      .then(function(info) {
        FileService.storeImage(newName);
        resolve();
      }, function(e) {
        reject();
      });
  });
})
}
```

You will also need cordovafile plugin to copy the file. You can find a tutorial that can guide you [here](https://devdactic.com/complete-image-guide-ionic/)

Comment: i'm making a secret vallet app using ionic 2, for that purpose its important for me to get the original path of image i select.

Comment: you should add the source of this info https://devdactic.com/complete-image-guide-ionic/